# Email delivery service - Sender address verification process

Tags: sendgrid, amazon-ses, postmark, mailjet

Our product needs a Email Delivery Service Provider to help us deliver emails. We want our customers to be able to use their own emailadresses when sending emails and that makes this a bit harder.

It seems that most companys verify sender adresses by sending an email with a link to that sender address. This is not a ideal solution for us (We don't want to tell our customer to wait for an Amazon email and click a link).

Is there any other verification processes out there, our maybe someone that don't have a verification process?

Comment: *"We want our customers to be able to use their own emailadresses when sending emails."*  You may believe that you want this, but you do not want this.  This is a good way to *be certain* that you will have deliverability problems.  Modern anti-spam capabilities like SPF, DKIM, and DMARC will make it impossible for you to originate mail as any address from a domain that uses these capabilities to prevent email sender forgery, which is technically what you are proposing to do.  Lack of malicious intent notwithstanding, it's still forgery when the mail comes from an unsanctioned  source system.

Comment: But MailChimp and others do this. They are using "on behalf of mcsv.net" in those cases. Read here https://kb.mailchimp.com/accounts/email-authentication/my-campaign-from-name-shows-mcsvnet 

I wan't to do that as well.

Comment: That article refers to mail from *your domain* showing "on behalf of" when you haven't configured DKIM.  SES does the same thing if not fully configured.  Consider this: [*"When you verify your email domain, MailChimp checks that you are using a valid From email address hosted at a domain you can access and aren't sending from domains that aren't actually yours. This will help keep your campaigns out of spam folders..."*](https://kb.mailchimp.com/accounts/email-authentication/verify-a-domain)  Also read the "Before You Start" section of that same page.  It doesn't work the way you want it to.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But what would o be nice, is the option to specify a verified "behalf of" together with the not verified from address my customer is using. The verified "behalf of" address has SPF etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify an entire domain with Postmark (where I work). This process won't send an email, but you'll need access to your customer's DNS settings. More info here: https://postmarkapp.com/support/article/1046-how-do-i-verify-a-domain